# jQuery change cursor on click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How I can change the cursor CSS property of a link element, so when the user click on that link, the cursor switches from pointer to wait?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('a.cursor_wait').click(function(){
    jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
  });
});
```

This works, but I must move with the mouse from the link to see the wait indicator, when I leave my cursor on the link, I still see the pointer.

How can I make this work without moving my cursor?

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/3WLGt/4/

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('a.cursor_wait').click(function(){
    jQuery('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
      jQuery(this).css('cursor', 'wait');
  });
});
```

Changes the property of the current link to the wait cursor as well, because by default they are set to pointer.

Comment: Chromium, trunk: still doesn't work without moving the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

you want only wait cursor on your link?
so why select body and change cursor?!

```
$('a').css('cursor','wait');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested) :

```
jQuery('body').trigger('hover');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work changing the class of the a, and changing the jquery to $ as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
        $(this).css('cursor', 'wait');
    });
});
```

However, this will work for all anchor tags a. You will need to specify the css class you want it to apply to.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly , you want click on a link ( for example DELETE an item ) then change the courser to wait until your request will be done, turn it back to default...

```
var c= confirm("Are you sure?");
if(c)
{ 
    document.body.style.cursor="wait";
    $.post("delete.php?id=212",function(data){
        alert('I\'ve done it...');
        document.body.style.cursor="default";
    });
}
```